# How to safe get value from object (return null when not exist)

Tags: javascript

I want to lookup for a key on an object, but if the key does't exist, it must return null, is it possible in JavaScript?

```js
const d = {
  A: () => { return 'A' },
  B: () => { return 'B' },
  C: () => { return 'C' },
}

const key = 'Z'

const func = d[key] // HERE

console.log(func)
```

Comment: Well you will get `undefined`, but if you really want `null`..   `const func = d[key]  || null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use or: `||`

or the newer [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

NOTE: the arrow function suggested by Máté Wiszt has to be wrapped in `()` or it will give an error

```js
const d = {
  A: () => { return 'A' },
  B: () => { return 'B' },
  C: () => { return 'C' },
}

let key = 'A'

let func = d[key] || null;
console.log(func && func())

key = 'Z'

func = d[key] || null
console.log(func && func())

func = d[key] || function() { return null };
console.log(func && func())

func = d?.[key] ?? (() => null); // arrow has to be wrapped
console.log(func())

// undefined key
let key1;
console.log({key1})

func = d?.[key1] ?? (() => null); // arrow has to be wrapped
console.log("Using undefined key1:",func())
```

Comment: Please don't modify your answer later to include others' answers.

Comment: what if `Z: undefined,` then all test case fail... You should use `hasOwnProperty` to check for existence of a property in an object

Comment: @MátéWiszt I do not see why. Your answer was wrong when I tested it so I updated mine with a working version. It was a good idea to return a function  - but yours failed

Comment: @decpk the optional chaining works for undefined keys

Comment: @MátéWiszt I gave you credit now...

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
const func = d[key] || () => null;
```

In this case you can call func safely.

Comment: That does not seem to be allowed

Comment: Yes, you will need to do `(() => null)`

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use `hasOwnProperty` to check wheather that property exist in the object `d` or not.

```js
const d1 = {
  A: () => { return "A"; },
  B: () => { return "B"; },
  C: () => { return "C"; },
  Z: undefined,
};

const d2 = {
  A: () => { return "A"; },
  B: () => { return "B"; },
  C: () => { return "C"; },
};

const key = "Z";

function getValue(obj, key) {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? obj[key] : null;
}

const func1 = getValue(d1, key);
console.log(func1);

const func2 = d1[key] || null;  // Shouldn't use
console.log(func2);

const func3 = d1[key] ?? null;  // Shouldn't use
console.log(func3);
```